# Torch 'Gather' Issue

Tags: lua, torch

I have two tensors as follows:

> Normalised Tensor :
>   1
>   10
>   94
>   [torch.LongStorage of size 3]

and

> Batch :
>   1
>   10
>    [torch.LongStorage of size 2]

I would like to use 'Batch' to select indices in the 3 dimension of 'Normalised Tensor'. So far I have used gather as follows:

normalised:long():gather(1, batch:long())

Unfortunately it's returning this error.
"bad argument #1 to 'gather' (Input tensor must have same dimensions as output"

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer is based on assuming the following: you have a three dimensional tensor of sizes x,y,z and you want a three dimensional tensor of size x,y,10 where the x,y slices are chosen based on indices listed in another tensor of size 1,10.

I, personally, have spent much time pondering what would be the possible use of the `gather` method. Only conclusion I've come to is: it not the problem described above.

The described problem is solvable by use of the [`index`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor-indexdim-index) function:

```
local slice = normalised:gather(3, batch[1]:long())
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

However, I instead am looking to use the integer(z) at index x,y of 'batch' to select the value at x,y,z of 'normalised', which will be output into a new tensor of size x,y

Comment: I don't quite get your description, if you want "z at index x,y of `batch`" then why is the `batch` essentially one-dimensional?